# Manifest merger failed about android studio

Tags: java, android-manifest

This is the error that i face in the android studio

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-34:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have conflicting `androidx` and `support` dependencies, double check them to remove any redundancies.